# using the AS command in a Sybase DB?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Having issues on what seems to be a simple query!

I'm trying to rename a column in the query results when querying a Sybase DB. Result is displaying the column with the name in the table View and not the rename. I tried the two queries below and getting results with the columns 'GAME_CODE' and 'ID_TYPE'. I want the results to display the columns 'CODE' and 'ACCT_TYPE'. No errors, just columns are not displaying as I would like.

TABLE = SPORTS_ACCOUNTS , Columns = GAME_CODE, ID_TYPE

```
SELECT GAME_CODE as 'CODE', ID_TYPE as 'ACCT_TYPE' FROM SPORTS_ACCOUNTS

SELECT GAME_CODE 'CODE', ID_TYPE 'ACCT_TYPE' FROM SPORTS_ACCOUNTS
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you paste a full code example as it works exactly as expected here on Sybase ASE:

```
1> use tempdb
2>
1> create table SPORTS_ACCOUNTS (GAME_CODE int, ID_TYPE int)
2>
1> insert into SPORTS_ACCOUNTS values (1,1)
2>
(1 row affected)
1> select GAME_CODE as 'CODE', ID_TYPE as 'ACCT_TYPE' from SPORTS_ACCOUNTS
2>
 CODE        ACCT_TYPE
 ----------- -----------
           1           1

(1 row affected)
1>
```

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that the Column Labels were being updated so I updated the Global Preferences to use the Column Labels in the DB Client (Squirrel) I was using. It seemed to solve the issue. Just not sure why with the default settings it was not updating the column name in the resultset.

Comment: SELECT xx.NUMBER, aa.GAME_CODE as 'CODE', aa.ID_TYPE as 'ACCT_TYPE' FROM SPORTS_ACCOUNTS aa
LEFT JOIN SPORTS_SCHED xx ON aa.GAME_CODE = xx.GAME_CODE